# como automatizar tarefa

Tags: python

recentemente tenho tido uma tarefa no trabalho repetitiva. o caso é o seguinte, eu preciso registrar certos equipamentos todos os dias (do mês 1 até o 6) a quantidade e a data.

ou seja

"(código do produto) (quantidade) (data)"

porém, isso vem ficando muito repetitivo e cansativo, queria saber se há uma forma de automatizar esse processo, pois há uma lista de funcionários e não sei bem como funciona automatização em python com listas.

é possível? se sim, como?

Answer (score -2):

Tem várias ferramentas para isso. Das básicas até as complexas.
Eu indico o [pyautogui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) que basicamente fará tudo que você faz usando teclado e mouse. (Funciona em primeiro plano, você não pode mexer no computador enquanto ele é executado).

Também existe o [selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/) e o [botcity](http://botcity.dev/)

Dá uma olhada [neste exemplo](https://github.com/elizeubarbosaabreu/BotInsta) onde usei o selenium para criar um bot para instagram...

Comment: Evite pedir para que leiam códigos em outro link/website. Poste os trechos de códigos relevantes no corpo da resposta, com uma boa descrição sobre o que o código deveria fazer, como deveria retornar os resultados.

Comment: Ok. Novato por aqui. rsrsrs